# How do I get Apache stats into munin when proxied from nginx?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, munin

I have munin plugins for mysql and nginx working, but, I'm not sure how to get the apache plugin working (it's there, I just haven't setup apache yet).

nginx proxies requests to apache running django and nginx is serving stats on 127.0.0.1/nginx_status so what do I setup apache for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the interactions to setup apache extended status as normal. I'm assuming you have apache running on 127.0.0.1:80 or 8080, so you'd configure the munin plugin for apache to to talk to that specific port /server-status

I'm assuming here that you know how to setup extended status, if you don't let me know and I can go into more detail once you tell us if you're using Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS/etc?

Comment: Just ask nginx for /server-status.  It will proxy the request back to Apache as it does with every other request.

When I'm setting up components that work together like this, I always start at the lowest level first and work up towards the highest level.  In this case, Apache first, then nginx, then Munin, then the Munin Apache plugin.

Comment: the ip address for server-status may not be the one you want to give access to. as long as you have the ip address stuff taken care of, that should work.